# Powershell error: "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Member'. The argument is null or empty."

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a quick script to add a AD group to a newly created Local server :

```
$ServerName = Read-Host 'New Server name?'
$ServerName|Foreach{
$GroupName = -join(“$_”,”-Admins”)
Write-Host $GroupName
Invoke-Command -computername $ServerName -scriptblock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' - 
Member $GroupName }
}
```

But I get the Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Member'. The argument is null or empty.   Any suggestions?  I have tried it several different ways and no joy.

Comment: you MUST pass the variables into a scriptblock when it is invoked that way. [*grin*] look at the `$Using:` scope modifier OR at adding parameters to the scriptblock.

Comment: Just figured that out!   Thanks!

Comment: kool! you are most welcome ... and i am glad  that you got it working as needed. [*grin*]